# Making more off forever in Octave

Tags: command-line, octave

Octave by default uses the "more" command to page results. It is possible to type "more off" to stop that in the current session. How can I stop it permanently without passing that command to Octave? (I want something like option, editing file, environment variable,...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is given in the documentation about [startup files](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Startup-Files.html) and the [more command](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Paging-Screen-Output.html). You just need to run `more off` on startup. To do this you can create the file `.octaverc` (the dot is important) in your home directory (`~/.octaverc`) and add the `more off` command to it. Now Octave should always start with more switched off.

(There's also the file `/usr/share/octave/site/m/startup/octaverc` if you have more than one user on the computer who want this configuration.)

Comment: Is there a way to make it system-wide?

Comment: What do you mean by "system wide"?

Comment: @عمروخضير I mean, you can create the file `.octaverc` (the dot is important) in your home directory and add the `more off` command to it. That way octave will always start with more switched off. (There's also `/usr/share/octave/site/m/startup/octaverc` if you have more than one user on the computer.)